# How do I change the maximum Upload File Size for the Document Manager in a Telerik RAD Controls RADEditor/WYSIWYG control?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dynamic-data, wysiwyg, rad-controls

I'm using the Telerik RAD Controls RADEditor/WYSIWYG control as part of a Dynamic Data solution.

I would like to be able to upload files using the Document Manager of this control.

However, these files are larger than whatever the default setting is for maximum upload file size.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

---

Thanks Yaakov Ellis, see your answer + the answer I linked through a comment for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Telerik website has instructions [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload_uploadinglargefiles.html).

Short version: in Web.config set the maxRequestLength

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout= "3600" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: See this answer in combination with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131728#131773

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/thread/b311D-ekgdc.aspx) in combination with [Yaakov Ellis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131728/how-do-i-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size-for-the-document-manager-in-a-tele#131737) may help others.

However, I've found for my problem, putting the following code in the code-behind for the user control FieldTemplate (Dynamic Data) in combination th [Yaakov Ellis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131728/how-do-i-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size-for-the-document-manager-in-a-tele#131737) solved things.

```
RadEditor1.DocumentManager.MaxUploadFileSize = 4194304;
```